# How to change the settings and add-ons in IE using VBScript?(without registry)

Tags: automated-testing, vbscript, ie9

I am trying to update the IE settings like (Security level, popups, Zoom ... ) and also wanted to enable addons in "Manage addons".

I wanted to updated those settings using VBscript/JavaScript with out using registry's.

Please help me with possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below Solution:

**Step 1:**

Get the Class ID from IE > Tools  > Manage  Add-ons

[image]

**Step 2:**

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings{47833539-D0C5-4125-9FA8-0819E2EAAC93}]
“Flags”=dword:00000001

Note: 0 is for enable and 1 is for disable.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any approach to enable or disable using IE Object ... like  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application"

Comment: Hello , I have sent you one reference link , Which is explain you in details. add-in-express.com/support/ie-vbnet-csharp.php. Still have any query then let me know.